# should I use constructor with HasTraits subclass

Tags: python, enthought, traitsui

I'm trying to learn how to make GUI with Traits. I'm new in object oriented programming and I'm new in Python. Most of the examples I could find on the net do not use any constructor in the Hastraits subclass. Should I forget about the def *init*(self, *arg) constructor? Or should I force myself to use it ?

For example, taking the example from :
[Change property parameter from within class constructor [Python / Traits]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9956167/change-property-parameter-from-within-class-constructor-python-traits)

the code from DrSAR is to me the most simple and elegant of all the examples; and yet it doesn't use constructor. Did I miss something?

Answer (score 3):

Short answer: no, don't write `__init__()` initializers when subclassing from `HasTraits`.

The `HasTraits` class defines a generic and very flexible `__init__()` that takes the keyword arguments given to it and assigns the values to the corresponding attributes. Your subclass will inherit this initializer. Given that the trait definitions usually provide sensible defaults for each attribute, there is usually no reason to need another initializer. There are cases where one does want to override this initializer, but they are relatively rare. I might only do so once every 100 or so classes that I write.

If you wanted practice writing initializers for standard subclassing-from-object Python, sorry. Traits has its own set of conventions and best practices that you will be learning in addition to the general OO and Python principles; some of the former will moot the latter.

Comment: Thank you, this solved a problem of mine that I could not figure out otherwise (problem: `@on_trait_change` was not working).